# Is O(m+n) the same as (O(max(m,n))?

Tags: sum, max, time-complexity, big-o

If I have two variables,say m and n,and my algorithm has time complexity O(m+n),is O(m,n) the same as having O(max(m,n))?If yes,can you explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Because O(m+n) is always smaller than O(2(m+n)), which only differs by a constant factor from O(m+n), and max(m+n) < 2(m+n). That's just one way to analyze it.

Comment: Can also one say that both complexities have the same asymptote?

Comment: Sure, because as either m or n or both tend to infinity, it can't go slower than 2m or 2n, whichever is larger. And constant factors don't matter in big-O notation.